# How to setup custom key repeating patterns in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I am using Windows 10 and when I am typing my keys are repeating.

When I press <kbd>e</kbd> it types `qe` and `ad` for <kbd>a</kbd> , `13` for <kbd>1</kbd>, `zc` for <kbd>c</kbd>, etc.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did your keyboard made any contact with liquids? Maybe during cleaning/disinfecting.

Comment: Does the computer have the same problem when you use a different keyboard? Is it a laptop?